# How to detect a QR code, take a snapshot and decode it in java using primefaces photocam feature

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, zxing

I have been trying to scan QR code using zxing and primefaces

```
    filename = getRandomImageName();
    byte[] data = captureEvent.getData();

    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getContext();
    String filePathToImage = servletContext.getRealPath("") + filename + ".jpeg";

    FileImageOutputStream imageOutput;
    try {
        imageOutput = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(filePathToImage));
        imageOutput.write(data, 0, data.length);
        imageOutput.close();
        String filePath = filePathToImage;
        String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
        Map hintMap = new HashMap();
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
        String scannedDetails = readQRCode(filePath, charset, hintMap);
        System.out.println("Data read from QR Code: " + scannedDetails);



        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('QRcodeDialog').hide();");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("baseTemplateForm:receiver");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        showMessage(Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE_ID, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "QR code not scanned properly. Please scan again.", null);
        throw new FacesException("Error in writing captured image.", e);

    } catch (NotFoundException e) {

        showMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_ID_FOR_QR, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "QR code not scanned properly. Please scan again.", null);
    } catch (CommandCenterException e) {
        logger.error("Error in fetching receiver details");
    }
```

What I want here is to continuously scan the image and detect QR code by itself instead of calling this function on click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

### `p:photoCam`

To continuously scan is not possible and not something you would like to do, keeping bandwidth and server load in mind. What you could do is use a [`p:poll`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) to capture a photo once every few seconds. To save bandwidth play with the `photoWidth`, `photoHeight` and `jpegQuality`. Reduce them as far back as you can. Also, don't start the poll immediately, but at the start of a button click, and stop it as soon as you've received a QR code.

### `pe:codeScanner`

From PrimeFaces Extension 10 and up you can use `pe:codeScanner` to scan QR codes. It's "live" and you can register an Ajax listener to send the scanned codes to a bean.

See:

- [Scan a QR code and decode it using p:photoCam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174091/scan-a-qr-code-and-decode-it-using-pphotocam)