# Scan a QR code and decode it using p:photoCam

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, camera, qr-code

I need to capture and read a QR Code while the camera is capturing, all of this in a JSF Application.

I have already read a QR Code in a photo, but for now I have to make it "alive".

Anyone has any suggestion?

I'm trying to use the p:photoCam of PrimeFaces.

This is the method, using Zxing to read the QR code:

```
 /**
   * 
   * @param filePath
   * @param charset
   * @param hintMap
   * 
   * @return Qr Code value 
   * 
   * @throws FileNotFoundException
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws NotFoundException
   */
  public static String readQRCode(String filePath, String charset, Map hintMap)
      throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException {
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
        new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
            ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filePath)))));
    Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap);
    return qrCodeResult.getText();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any JSF or PrimeFaces related code/attempt in here

Comment: That's not yet possible using a PrimeFaces component. See https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/812

Comment: I got it!!!

Now my problem is to open the camera in chrome or firefox, using primefaces 6.1.RC2, but I know that the p:photoCam of this version isn't perfect. How can I update just this component and keep my Primefaces version?

Comment: Why would you want to stay on a release candidate? I would suggest to upgrade to PrimeFaces 9 the moment it is released. Just to give you an example, there is a XSS vulnerability in jQuery which is fixed in 9. https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=63144

Answer (score 3):

PrimeFaces Extensions 10 will have a `pe:codeScanner` component to scan bar and QR codes from a device camera.

```html
<pe:codeScanner width="600"
                height="400">
  <p:ajax event="codeScanned"
          listener="#{codeScannerController.onCodeScanned}"/>
</pe:codeScanner>
```

Source: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/blob/master/showcase/src/main/webapp/sections/codeScanner/example-basicUsage.xhtml

```java
public void onCodeScanned(final SelectEvent<Code> event) {
    final Code code = event.getObject();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            String.format("Scanned: %s (%s)", code.getValue(), code.getFormat()),
                            null));
}
```

Source: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/blob/master/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/showcase/controller/codescanner/CodeScannerController.java